# Wordpress - CSS no se muestra correctamente en Front End

Tags: wordpress, frontend

Tengo este sitio web: layher.mx. El sitio se muestra correctamente en wp-admin si intento modificar algún contenido de las páginas, pero al  visualizarlo en Front-End pareciera que los estilos CSS no están cargando del todo correctamente. Hay bloques encimándose, y paddings y margins que no son respetados en los elementos como botones.

Cuando se entregó el sitio, funcionaba corerctamente, pero después de un tiempo termina por dejar de cargar correctamente los estilos CSS.

¿Hay forma de solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Ahora mismo yo veo la página correctamente. Pero seguramente hay algún plugin de optimización aplazando la carga de CSS.

Si no usas ningún plugin de optimización ve a los ajustes de elementor (Elementor>Ajustes>Experimentos) y desactiva la carga de CSS mejorada.